# Moving from UUID to auto-increment keys

Tags: mysql, database

I have a huge MySQL database with around 400 tables. This database is generated by a CRM, and we are moving on to maintain our own MySQL database.

The primary keys in the whole schema is generated by MySQL UUID() function. Now, I do not want to continue using UUIDs because of some obvious reasons -

1. Too huge to store
2. inserts are slow, because of randomness in BTREE (defragmented pages in memory)
3. indexing is affected, obviously not as fast as you get with
   auto-increment ints

But its benefits are that its unique, which is guaranteed by auto-increment ints too.

All the data in this schema has relationships all over (not enforced by foreign keys through) based on ids. For example, an ID of a row in a table is stored in a cross reference table of many-to-many relationship

I want to change the IDs from UUIDs to auto-increments, while still maintaining the new auto-incremented keys all over the data. I do not want to mess up my current data. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

We are using InnoDB engine

Thanks.

Comment: If by "easy" you mean something like `ALTER ALL TABLES SET PK STYLE=AUTOINCREMENT` the answer is no. You will have to do this table by table. You may wish to consider whether the cost of your labor exceeds like lifetime cost of upgrading your server hardware and leaving these UUIDs in place. It probably does.

Comment: By easy i meant that if I can write a stored proc or a set of queries which basically replace the id values with auto incremented int value of a row in different tables, I am good with that too. I am also okay to specify what all tables need to be updated for a given record.